# How to create custom metaprogramming test structs using C++11 type_traits?

Tags: c++, testing, c++11, metaprogramming, type-traits

How can I write custom metaprogamming tests in C++11? I would like to write something like this:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

struct A {};

template <typename T>
struct foo {
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_pointer<T>::value,
                                      typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type,
                                      T>::type type;
};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct test1{typedef typename std::is_same<A, B>::value result;};

template <typename A, typename B>
struct test2{typedef typename std::is_same<A, typename foo<B>::type>::value result;};

template <typename A, typename B>
void testAll() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "test1: " << typename test1<A,B>::result << std::endl; // ERROR: expected ‘(’ before ‘<<’ token
    std::cout << "test2: " << typename test2<A,B>::result << std::endl; // ERROR: expected ‘(’ before ‘<<’ token
    // ...
}

int main()
{  
    typedef A type1;
    testAll<A, type1>();
    typedef const A* type2;
    testAll<A, type2>();
    // ...
}
```

I saw a possible is_same implementation from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same). Do I need something like that?

It's possible to write this:

```
std::cout << "test1: " << std::is_same<A, B>::value << std::endl;
```

I would like to write this:

```
 std::cout << "test1: " << test1<A, B>::result << std::endl;
```

Comment: `std::is_same` is part of C++11. That "possible implementation" is not intended for you to copy into your project, just to aid in your understanding of how the template works.

Comment: BTW your conditional in `struct foo` is unnecessary. `std::remove_pointer` just returns the type directly if it wasn't a pointer.

Comment: @KevinBallard yep you're right, the example is simpler than the use I intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `typename` before `test1<A,B>::result`, but that's inappropriate, because you want `result` to be a *value*, not a type. For the same reason, you should not define it as a type alias inside `test1<>`: you simply want it to have the same *value* returned by `std::is_same<>::value` (that is a `static const bool` member variable, not a type name).

You could write it this way:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct test1
{ 
    static const bool result = std::is_same<A, B>::value;
};
```

So that the following line will compile:

```
std::cout << "test1: " << test1<A,B>::result << std::endl;
```

However, your `test1<>` trait would be little more than an alias for `std::is_same<>` (with `result` instead of `value`), and C++11 supports alias templates:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
using test1 = std::is_same<A, B>;
```

This would allow you to do:

```
std::cout << "test1: " << test1<A,B>::value << std::endl;
```

The `test2<>` trait suffers from a similar problem, in that it defines `result` as a type alias, but `std::is_same<A, typename foo<B>::type>::value` is a value, not a type.

So once again you *could* rewrite it as follows:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct test2
{
    static const bool result = std::is_same<A, typename foo<B>::type>::value;
};
```

So that the following line will compile:

```
std::cout << "test2: " << test2<A, B>::result << std::endl;
```

But again, you could as well define an alias template:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
using test2 = std::is_same<A, typename foo<B>::type>;
```